# MySQL Deleting rows from the database

Tags: mysql, delete-row, sql-delete

I'm storing a simple tag relationship and I'm wondering what would be the better way to delete tags?

The two ways I know of:

1. SELECT tag FROM content_tags WHERE
   content_id = 10
2. Use php to compare the result with
       the new tags supplied and if there
       are any tags from the database
       result that are not in the new tags,
       run a delete query on that tag
3. The rest of the tags are either new
       or already exist so I use INSERT
       INTO content_tags ... ON DUPLICATE
       KEY UPDATE

Or simply:

1. DELETE FROM content_tags FROM tags
   WHERE content_id = 10
2. Insert each tag (no need to use ON
   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE here as the
   tags for  this content_id are
   already deleted at this point)

I'm current doing the first method, but the 2nd way seems to be much less of a hassle. But I'm not sure if it's "bad" or inefficient to use delete in this fashion. Or if you have a better method feel free to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adjust the first method to do also not do the inserts on tags that already exist. But it could (and probably will) still result in more queries then the second method, especially if you combine those insert statements in a single query.

//small example :)

```
INSERT INTO content_tags
(content_id, tag_id)
VALUES
(1,1),
(1,2),
(1,3);
```

Comment: I'm more worried about deleting the records, maybe you misunderstood me? For example, let's say you have tag_id 1,3,5,7,9 stored for content_id 10. Now I go to update the tags and remove 3 and 5, so tag_id is now 1,7,9. So of course I need to delete tag_id 3 and 5, but I'd need to use php to compare them when it's much easier just to delete all the tags 1,3,5,7,9 and then just insert 1,7,9 instead. I'm just wondering if it's bad for the database to do this?

Comment: @Joker, I don't think it matters. Databases are basically made for these kinds of operations. So I don't think you have to worry about doing stuff that is bad for the database through regular queries. If you start manipulating the database through File Manipulation then you should start worrying about damaging the database.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I'm now going to use the 2nd way ease. :)